# char to ascii - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

i want to convert char array to ascii,

i started trying with NSString, characterAtIndex ( failed due to lack of knowledge about manipulating unichar )

creating a char array and passing it to a NSString using stringWithCString ( failed due to lack of knowledge about encoding )

now at the end i am convincing myself using normal char array and type casting it into int.

but my mind says this is not a good practice.

Please tell me is there another Objective-C type solution, or is this the only solution.

I'm a beginner and am working on GNUStep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` models a Unicode string. To get the C-string encoding, use `-[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]` which returns a `const char *`. You'll have to supply the encoding you want to use. For ASCII, use the `NSASCIIStringEncoding` constant:

```
const char *asciiCString = [myString cStringWithEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: I'm at very beginner stage, that's why this question.
Thanks for the patience to answer such a naive question.

Comment: We were all beginners once! Good luck, Sumit.

Answer (score 0):

You either want to work with a char-array, which is probably a C-string, and already in ASCII, OR You can use an NSString, which is in unicode, and is an opaque data type.

If you're using NSString, use the appropriate NSString functions, and you don't ever really need to convert to a char*...