# How to get the Ascii Integer value of the first letter of a NSString in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

In Objective-C, how to get the Ascii Integer value of the first letter of a NSString?

Comment: Is the string a c-string or an NSString?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840436/char-to-ascii-objective-c

Comment: NSString.  Thx Javed but that does not help as I want an integer value as the returned result.

Comment: Technically, you can't.  There's no guarantee that the first character of an NSString is in the ASCII range.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ([aString length] > 0) {
    unichar firstCharacter = [aString characterAtIndex: 0];
    // ...
}
```

That's all. `unichar` is an alias of `unsigned short` and so is an integer type. However, there is no guarantee the character is part of ASCII, as `NSString` is Unicode-based.

Answer (score 3):

```
unichar ch = [myString characterAtIndex:0]
```

Now as the name specified, it returns the unicode character value unichar which is actually a typedef of unsigned short. NSString is not ASCII string, but if the first character is really an ASCII character then you will get the correct ASCII value. And if the string is empty then this will raise an exception.