# Get NSString Number Representation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I've been working on an encryption algorithm and now I'd like to encrypt an entire string instead of just numbers. How to I get the number Representation of each character in Objective-C? I already have an Array containing all the single characters of the given string, I just need to find a way to get a number out of it.
I'm not sure if iOS uses unicode, but if Id just need to get the unicode value and convert it to a number right? But how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4422470/2553526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption algorithm usually operate on a sequence of bytes, so you should choose a
*string encoding* to convert the `NSString` (which uses Unicode internally) to a 
byte sequence. For example:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello World";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data); //  <48656c6c 6f20576f 726c64f0 9f9884>
const uint8_t *bytes = [data bytes]; // Pointer to UTF-8 bytes
NSUInteger length = [data length];   // Number of UTF-8 bytes
```

Now you can encrypt `bytes[0], ..., bytes[length-1]` (which are all in the range 0 .. 255).

Comment: Thank you :) That works! And how do I decode the number again? When I decode my message and have all the unicode numbers again?

Comment: @user3207681: `NSString *decoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: Ok when I decode the message again I found my original number again for each character. How do I get the byte and length information out of it?

Comment: @user3207681: Sorry, I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Ok Im sorry :). When I decode the code I'm left with an array of integers containing the byte numbers. How to I turn those integers back into my bytes and then my original string.

Comment: @user3207681: You have to fill an array of `uint8_t` and then use `initWithBytes:...` as shown above. - If this does not help, please update your question with the code that you have so far. Alternatively, consider to post a new question so that more people have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you so much :)! I've been playing around with it for hours, but now it works!